# Efficiency of a code

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

How to find the efficiency (big O notation) in finding the total of each row of a 2d array

```
void findTotal(int arr[3][],int rows,int cols)
{ 
    int *total=new int[rows];
    int sum;
    for(int r=0;r<rows;r++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(int c=0;c<cols;c++)
            sum=sum+arr[r][c];
        total[r]=sum;
    }
    for(int k=0;k<rows;k++)
        cout<<total[k]<<endl;
    delete []total;
}
```

Comment: You can find it by learning some theoretical computer science.

Comment: Oh, and before you ask "I know but what's the result", it's `O(rows * cols)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, it is `O(cols)`. If `rows>3` you might get a segfault after 4 iterations.

Comment: @amit If we are splitting hair: 1. in function arguments, `T arr[N]` and `T arr[]` and `T *arr` are equivalent, you don't really know that there are 3 rows; 2. this code doesn't even compile, `int arr[3][]` is not a valid declarator; 3. Even if there are at most 3 rows, it **is** `O(rows * cols)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 The point is, if you have a hard bound on `rows` - it is not a factor of the final big O notation. If it is HW assignment, it could be what the question is all about.

Comment: @amit Well, as I just stated, we **don't** have such a bound.

Comment: @H2CO3 `T* arr`, `T arr[]` and `T arr[N]` aren't equivalent actually. Assuming we're talking about templates.

Comment: @Rapptz Did you read my **entire** comment? "in function arguments"... I'm not saying that they're equivalent in general, because arrays are not pointers, of course. It's just that arrays decay into a pointer when passed to a function, and as such, function arguments **can't** be arrays, only pointers, so in a function declaration, in the argument list, `T [N]`, `T []` and `T *` **are equivalent.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

I hope this explanation clears things up a little.

Efficiency is can basically be defined as

> "Growth of functions in terms of input size n."

Big O notation lets you classify algorithms by how they respond (in terms of time or space requirements) to changes in input size.

In your case, your input is a 2D array, that has a number of rows and a number of columns. Your `for` loop goes through every row, and the nested one goes through every column of every row in your 2D array. **H2CO3** is right, the Big O of this function is `O(rows*columns)`

Other examples of different efficiencies are:

> O(n) - linear - grows at the same speed as the input size; example - finding an item in an unsorted array
>
> O(1) - constant - does not grow - stays the same; example - hash tables.
>
> O(log n) - logarithmic; example: binary search
>
> O(n log n) - linearithmic; example: merge sort, quicksort etc

For more info, you should always Google your question.

Wikipedia also has a list of great articles about computer science, like [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and so on.